# Calendar Tagging In

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

Is there an existing solution or a way in ASP.NET MVC that could render data such as below in a calendar tagging way table in a monthly view?

```
+--------------+-----------------------------+------------+-----+-----------+-----------+
| account_name |     PositionDescription     |  FullDate  | Day |  DayName  | ShiftType |
+--------------+-----------------------------+------------+-----+-----------+-----------+
| employee1    | Customer Support Specialist | 2012-11-01 |   1 | Thursday  | G         |
| employee1    | Customer Support Specialist | 2012-11-03 |   3 | Saturday  | G         |
| employee1    | Customer Support Specialist | 2012-11-05 |   5 | Monday    | G         |
| employee1    | Customer Support Specialist | 2012-11-06 |   6 | Tuesday   | G         |
| employee1    | Customer Support Specialist | 2012-11-08 |   8 | Thursday  | G         |
| employee1    | Customer Support Specialist | 2012-11-10 |  10 | Saturday  | G         |
| employee1    | Customer Support Specialist | 2012-11-12 |  12 | Monday    | G         |
| employee1    | Customer Support Specialist | 2012-11-13 |  13 | Tuesday   | G         |
| employee1    | Customer Support Specialist | 2012-11-15 |  15 | Thursday  | G         |
| employee1    | Customer Support Specialist | 2012-11-17 |  17 | Saturday  | G         |
| employee1    | Customer Support Specialist | 2012-11-19 |  19 | Monday    | G         |
| employee1    | Customer Support Specialist | 2012-11-20 |  20 | Tuesday   | G         |
| employee1    | Customer Support Specialist | 2012-11-22 |  22 | Thursday  | G         |
| employee1    | Customer Support Specialist | 2012-11-24 |  24 | Saturday  | G         |
| employee1    | Customer Support Specialist | 2012-11-26 |  26 | Monday    | G         |
| employee1    | Customer Support Specialist | 2012-11-27 |  27 | Tuesday   | G         |
| employee1    | Customer Support Specialist | 2012-11-29 |  29 | Thursday  | G         |    
+--------------+-----------------------------+------------+-----+-----------+-----------+
```

Thank You!
Sherwin

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure if this is what you're after, but [FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) is a fairly nice jQuery calendar plugin, and there's at least one tutorial for how to integrate it with MVC: http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2010/02/03/using-fullcalendar-jquery-component-with-asp-net-mvc.aspx